# Is the following proof correct?-Finite Ring Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Show that the following conditions are equivalent in $R=\mathbb Z_n$.
>   Let $[x],[y] \in \mathbb Z_n$.
>
> 1. $R[x]+R[y]=R$
> 2. $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

$(1)\implies (2)$::

When $R=\mathbb Z_n$, then $R[x]=\langle [x]\rangle $ and $R[y]=\langle [y]\rangle $ where $\langle [x]\rangle, \langle [y]\rangle $ denote the ideal generated by $[x],[y]$ respectively.

Now $R[x]+R[y]=R
\implies \langle [x]\rangle +\langle [y]\rangle =\mathbb Z_n$.

Since $[1]\in \mathbb Z_n$ so $[1]\in  \langle [x]\rangle +\langle [y]\rangle$ which implies that there exists integers $m,k$ such that $m[x]+k[y]=1\implies mx+ky\equiv 1 \mod n\implies \gcd(x,y)=1$

$(2)\implies (1)$::

$\gcd(x,y)=1\implies mx+ky=1$ for some $m,k\in \mathbb Z$

$m[x]+k[y]=[1] \implies [1]\in Rx+Ry\implies R=Rx+Ry$.

Is the above proof correct?
My professor always has a knack of cutting marks.

Can someone please go through the above proof and give some comments if there is anyting wrong and if I need to correct something ?

If someone can help, I will be grateful.

Comment: Your proof is correct. :)

Comment: This is a very badly worded question. The elements of ${\mathbb Z}_n$ are not integers, they are congruence classes of integers. So $\gcd(x,y)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @DerekHolt; is the question framed correctly now?

Comment: @DerekHolt; can you please go through the proof now and lemme know if its correct

Comment: I'm checking if $m[x]+k[y]=1\implies mx+ky\equiv 1 \mod n\implies \gcd(x,y)=1$ holds true.

Comment: It's not group but ring theory.

Comment: @Berci; edited the question, do lemme know for any further corrections

Comment: I might be missing something but $m[x]+k[y]=1\implies mx+ky\equiv 1 \mod n\implies \gcd(x,y)=1$ doesn't seem to hold for $x=6$, $y=3$ , $n=24$, $m=3$, $k=2$

Comment: If, for example, $n=5$, then $[2]=[7]$ but $\gcd(2,7) \ne \gcd(2,2)$. You should perhaps assume that $x,y \in {\mathbb Z}$ with $0 \le x,y < n$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement (2)$\implies$(1) is true and you proved it correctly.

The statement (1)$\implies$(2) is not true in general.

Indeed, you correctly show that $R[x]+R[y]=R$ implies $mx+ky\equiv1\pmod{n}$, for some integers $m$ and $k$, but this doesn't imply $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

For instance, with $n=15$, you have $R[7]+R[14]=R$, but certainly $\gcd(7,14)$ doesn't equal $1$.

Comment: One more question : When is the implication $(1) \to  (2)$ true?

Comment: @Math_Freak There are counterexamples for every $n$, because for every $n$ we have $R[n-1]+R[n-1]=R$. If $n=2$, you can use $R[3]+R[9]=R$. If you *assume* that $0\le x,y<n$, then only $n=2$ works.